# Can't create a container buiding a zoo

Tags: java

I am trying to Implement a `Zoo` class which will hold your `Animals` (panda and elephant). Inside this class, you should have a list or array of `Animal` objects, and that container should be able to hold at least 5 animals

Your `Zoo` class should also have a function `void addAnimal(Animal a)` that allows you to add animals to the zoo container. These `Animal` objects should be instances of your child classes, and this function should not return anything.

Now that you have all your objects, it's time to write a `main()` function to test them. Make a `ZooBuilder` class which contains a `main()` function that creates a `Zoo` and five `Animals`, then adds the `Animals` to the `Zoo`. This is all well and good, but doesn't yet give you any useful output.

So, extend your `Animal` class to have a method `void printInfo()` to print out the `Animal`'s name, species and age on the same line. So, for example, if you have a `Panda` named "Spot" that is 10 years old, the `printInfo()` function should print output similar to this:

I created the classes for `Animal` which extends to `Panda` and `Elephant`.
I (try) to create the zoo container to which the animals will be added.

When I run the `Zoobuilder` class and `main` function, the return is:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Zoo cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animal {
  String name;
  String species;
  int age;
  public Animal () {}
  public Animal (String name, String species, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.species = species;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

public class Elephant extends Animal {

  public String species;

  public Elephant () {

  }
  public Elephant (String name, String species, int age){
    super (name, species, age);
    this.name = "Elle";
    this.species = "Elephant";
  }
}

public class Panda extends Animal {
  public String species;     

  public Panda () {}

  public Panda (String name, String species, int age){

    super (name, species, age);
    this.name = "Spot";
    this.species="Panda";
  }
}

public class Zoo extends Animal  {

  public ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

  public void addAnimal(Animal a)
  {
    animals.add(a);
  }

  void printAllInfo()

public class Zoobuilder {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Zoo = new Zoo();

      Panda Spot = new Panda ("Spot", "Panda", 0);
      Elephant Elle = new Elephant ("Elle", "Elephant", 0);
      new Animal ();
      new Animal ();
      new Animal ();
  }
```

Comment: You forgot the variable name.

Comment: Please reconsider if Zoo should really extend Animal. I might be wrong and this is totally intended but personally I would struggle arguing why a Zoo needs a `species` field - addionally none of the inherited fields and methods were used on Zoo either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks close. Here are a few suggestions.

1. Modify the `Zoo` class so it does not extend `Animal`. The Zoo can *contain* an Animal, but the definition of a Zoo itself is not some kind of Animal. so change this: `class Zoo extends Animal` to this: `class Zoo`. This is an improvement, you could elect to leave it as is, but it seems unlikely that your "Zoo" is also an "Animal".
2. Declare a proper "zoo" variable. Right now, you're getting a compliation error, so change this: `Zoo = new Zoo();` to something like this: `Zoo theZoo = new Zoo();`. Then you'll have a variable named "theZoo" to use later.
3. Follow naming conventions and start variable names with a lowercase letter. Instead of `Panda Spot` and `Elephant Elle` – which declare variables "Spot" (with a capital "S") and "Elle" (capital "E") – use lowercase names: `Panda spot` and `Elephant elle`.
4. Finally, add animals to your zoo: `theZoo.addAnimal(spot);` and `theZoo.addAnimal(elle);`
5. Remove the duplicate variables of `species`. Every `Animal` has this: `String species;` – which defines a `species` member variable with package scope. Separately, both `Elephant` and `Panda` define this: `public String species` – which defines a different `species` member variable with public scope. There's more to say on this point for sure, but here's the suggestion to fix your code: leave a single `species` variable on `Animal`, and remove the others.

As an example for the last point, here's all that's needed to define a new `Cat` class (note the absence of any member variables defined on `Cat` – they aren't needed, because it gets them from `Animal`)

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat(String name, String species, int age) {
        super(name, species, age);
    }
}
```

and here's some code to create a cat and print it's name:

```
Cat cat = new Cat("Foofy", "Tabby", 7);
System.out.println(cat.name);
```

Comment: great! I understood the errors and now the code is ok! One last question: how can I use the "void printInfo()" to print out the Animal's name, species and age on the same line. ? Thanks

Comment: Each time you call `theZoo.addAnimal(...)`, it will be added to the `animals` list. In your `printInfo()` method, you can access `animals`. For example, you could do this: `System.out.println(theZoo.size());` to print the number of animals in the zoo. I'm trying to avoid solving the whole thing for you, but I think your next step is to learn how to iterate over a list.

Comment: I tried the following code, but it is returning "the method size () is undefined for the type Zoo"  for (int i=0;i<theZoo.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println (theZoo.get(i));
   }

Comment: sorry... typo above. try: `animals.size()` – the `size()` method is available on your animals ArrayList. also, `theZoo` is not a list that you can iterate. instead, try to iterate your `animals` list.

Comment: I tryed animals.size () and animals.get (i)but I'm getting the same error message...

Comment: Comments are not a good way to resolve further questions. If you have a specific question (or questions), it would best to either research them each individually or ask new, specific questions for each.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is giving you an error because you did not assign a pointer to the newly instantiated zoo class.

This is incorrect:

```
Zoo = new Zoo();
```

This is correct:

```
Zoo variableName = new Zoo();
```

then later you can call

```
variableName.addAnimal(Elle);
```